Join indirect tables using sequalize in nodejs
Tables are defined as follows:
const Client = db.define('clients', {
    client_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
});

Client.hasMany(Project, {foreignKey: 'project_client_id'});


const Project = db.define('projects', {
    project_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    project_client_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    }
});

Project.hasMany(Assignment, {foreignKey: 'assignment_project_id'});

const Assignment = db.define('assignments', {
    assignment_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    assignment_status: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['Started', 'In-Progress', 'Closed'],
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'Started'
    },
    assignment_project_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    }
});

I wanted query all assignments with given client_id, project_id, assignment_id, or assignment_status. All these query parameters are optional. If none given all assignments must be returned. How to write code for Assignment.findAll in this scenario?
I tried to add include Client in Assignment.findAll, got error Error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: clients is not associated to assignments!

To work with associations usually you need to define them by pairs like belognsTo/hasMany:
Client.hasMany(Project, {foreignKey: 'project_client_id'});
Project.belongsTo(Client, {foreignKey: 'project_client_id'});

Project.hasMany(Assignment, {foreignKey: 'assignment_project_id'});
Assignment.belongsTo(Project, {foreignKey: 'assignment_project_id'});

Because one Sequelize model does not know anything about other model's associations even if it was passed as an associated model to belongsTo/hasMany
